# Customization of UITabBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, uitabbar

I am using `UITabBar` with 3 tab bar items. I want to customize center tab item. like raised tab bar button.

I know how to add `UITabBarController` and customizing that. But I want to customize `UITabBar`.

I want to add a customized button to tab bar as a center tab bar item, like this:

[image]

Comment: My problem to use UITabBarController is, when i add it i have to enable any one of the tab. But i want none of the tab selected. I tried [tabbarController setSelectedViewController=nil]. but when i select the tab, it's not working. That's why i am using tabbar and navigating through navigation controller.

Answer (score 1):

check this http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/

```
UIButton* button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    button.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, buttonImage.size.width, buttonImage.size.height);
    [button setBackgroundImage:buttonImage forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [button setBackgroundImage:highlightImage forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];

    CGFloat heightDifference = buttonImage.size.height - self.tabBar.frame.size.height;
    if (heightDifference < 0)
      button.center = self.tabBar.center;
    else
    {
      CGPoint center = self.tabBar.center;
      center.y = center.y - heightDifference/2.0;
      button.center = center;
    }

    [self.view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: hi Rahul.. In your answer you are considering UITabBarController but I have added UITabBar. I have created custom UITabBarItem and I am Trying to add a button as a subview of that UITabBarItem.

Answer (score 0):

you can change

```
  backgroundImage  property
  selectedImageTintColor  property
  selectionIndicatorImage  property
  tintColor  property
```

of a uitabbar

maybe you can achive with a background image. If not then you have to write your own tabbar.

Comment: Mert - thanks for responding.. 
But what i am trying to do is I am customizing uitabbaritem and there i am adding a button as a subview of uibaritem. like [self.view addsubview:button]; but it's showing error like view is not a method of self(uibaritem). and mainly i want that particular shape for that center button.